# how to print json array to jquery table with json in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, json, laravel

```
public function store( $customername)
{

$projectname=DB::table("selectproject")->where("customername",$customername)->pluck("projectname","id");

    $paidamount = DB::table("payment")->where("projectname",$projectname)->sum("amount","id");

    $sitenumber = DB::table("sites")->where("projectname",$projectname)->pluck("sitenumber","id");

    $array = array(  $projectname, $paidamount,  $sitenumber);

    return json_encode($array);
 }


  my blade file 

@include('projects.home')

 <form action="{{ route('siteallocate.store') }}" method="post" >
 @csrf

   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

      <div class="form-group">

      <strong>Select customer :</strong>

      <select class="form-control" name="customername">
           <option selected="true" disabled="disabled"  >--Select--</option>

    @foreach ($data as $row)

        <option class="form-control" value="{{$row->customername  }}" >{{ $row->customername }}     
       </option>

 @endforeach
</select>
</div>

</div>
<div id="tableview" >

 </div>

 </form>


     <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function (){


          jQuery('select[name="customername"]').on('change',function(){

           var alreadyAdded = [];

                   var categoryID = jQuery(this).val();
                   if(categoryID)

                   {
                       
                      jQuery.ajax({
                          
                         url : '/hi/'+categoryID,
                         type : "GET",
                         dataType : "json",
                         success:function(data)
                         {
                        
                       
                         $('#tableview').html("")

                            jQuery.each(data, function(key,value){

                             //if(data === null) { alert('empty') } // skip nulls


                            
                            
                            
                             if ($.inArray(this.value, alreadyAdded) !== -1) { return;  }

                              $('#tableview').html("")
                               $('#tableview').append('<table class="table table-bordered" > 
 <tr > 
class="bg-info"> <th> Customername </th> <th> Projectname </th> <th> Amount </th>  <th> Sitenumber 
</th>  </tr>

  <tr>??
 <td> ' + categoryID+'</td>   <td> ' +data[0][0]+'</td>  <td> ' + data[0][1]+'</td>  <td> <div 
 class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">  <select class="form-control"   > <option> ' + 
 data[0][3]+'</option>  </select> </div> </td>   
</tr>    </table>');

                              alreadyAdded.push(this.value);

                            });
                         }
                      });
                   }
                  
                });

              });

            
        </script>
```

Display table by selecting the customername from the dropdown and the data come from database against
customername in function store () i have to place the customername and projectname column in the table
sitenumber should be placed in selectbox  i tried with data[0][0]['3'] like index number
but Is  there is no way to determine the next key ??  its shows [Object object ] in the table .
How to issue this problem?

Comment: Please Read How To Ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And Give A Minimal Example.

Comment: help me brother  i will try my best

Comment: you need to do some research on your own. without any example of what you exactly want, we would not be able to help you. what is the result you are currently getting? where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: show output of `data` and expected output as well.

Comment: @Gopalkrish what i suggest you to do is run a foreach loop on the PHP page where you are sending the ajax request. then render the HTML part there and simply echo it. so the data variable would be containing all the rows. then you can simply append the rows to the table.

Comment: @Swati  output of the  data  by using this  JSON.stringify(data)  is   [{"3":"gopal"},[{"amount":74500}]{"18":"gopal1","19":"gopal2"}]  this is  i was expecting but  my problem how to print this   array  in the Projectname column  as gopal and Amount column as 74500 and sitenumber column as gopal1,gopal2 in dropdown box

Comment: change `array(  $projectname, $paidamount,  $sitenumber)` to `array(  "name"=>$projectname,"amt"=> $paidamount, "site"=> $sitenumber)` then show output of that as well.

Comment: @Swati {"name":{"3":"gopal"},"amt":[{"amount":74500}],"site"{"18":"gopal1","19":"gopal2"}}

Comment: There will be only 1 row or more rows ?

Comment: There will be only one row and site number will be multiple in dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there will be only 1 row so you do no need to use `.each` loop you can retrieve value of json using key directly and for `sites` as there will be mutliple values you can use `.each` loop to iterate through your jsons and append option inside your select-box

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#tableview').html("")
//suppose return data look like this
var data = {
  "name": {
    "3": "gopal"
  },
  "amt": [{
    "amount": 74500
  }],
  "site": {
    "18": "gopal1",
    "19": "gopal2",
    "20": "gopal3"
  }
}
$('#tableview').append('<table class="table table-bordered"><tr class = "bg-info"><th> Projectname </th> <th> Amount </th><th> Sitenumber </th></tr>')
//append new row
$('#tableview table').append("<tr><td></td><td></td><td><select></select></td></tr>")
//add text to first td
$('#tableview tr:last td:eq(0)').text(data["name"][Object.keys(data["name"])])
//add amt to 2nd td
$('#tableview tr:last td:eq(1)').text(data["amt"][0]["amount"])
//loop through sites..
$.each(data["site"], function(key, value) {
  //append options
  $('#tableview tr:last select').append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value + "</option>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableview"></div>
```